# managedObjectContext sent to instance error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am using core data to add data to my tableview from this tutorial

"http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-to-core-data/" and

I have no bugs, but when I click run I get this error
 -[AppDelegate managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

What does the error mean? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Try to access it from the core data container in app delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Means that 'AppDelegate' doesn't know how to answer to 'managedObjectContext'.

Double check that managedObjectContext is accesible from the AppDelegate instance.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I needed it very much. Should i add a property for it in the app delegate.h file? or how do i exactly check that? i'm sorry but i'm new to using core data.

Comment: I would recommend to start a new project from scratch and select "Use core data" on the initial setup process. There you could learn how to setup properly the Core Data stack.